# Error al insertar string en base de datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy trabajando con python y tengo la siguiente variable:
`pantalla="LCD"` Al usar el código

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = f"UPDATE tabla SET pantalla = {pantalla} WHERE id = 1 "
    cursor.execute(sql) 
    connection.commit()
except:
    print(f"pantalla no agregado en ID: {i}")
```

Me muestra el `except`. 
Mi columna esta configurada como `VARCHAR(50)` y en Cotejamiento tiene `utf8mb4_general_ci`.
Este problema me pasa con todas las variables que son tipo string. No se si esta mal condigurada la tabla o en qué estoy fallando. Pero con las variables float que tengo, funciona normal.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando tienes un error parecido a éste, te recomiendo que muestres la consulta que quieres insertar, por ejemplo print(sql). Y verás que estas haciendo pantalla=sql  cuando debería ser  `pantalla ='sql'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sé qué representa la `f` en tu código ¿?

Por otra parte, deberías aplicar consultas preparadas, a fin de evitar ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

De este modo debería funcionar:

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
    stmt = "UPDATE tabla SET pantalla = %s WHERE id = 1"
    cursor.execute(stmt,(pantalla)) 
    connection.commit()
except:
    print("pantalla no agregado en ID: {i}")
```

Sobre las consultas preparadas puedes revisar [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html). Se trata de poner un marcador `%s` en lugar del dato, el cual se pasa luego en el `execute`, esto evita que el valor de `pantalla` (u otro proveniente del exterior) sea manipulado para ejecutar código malicioso en la consulta.

Comment: La f le da formato de string, pero como lo está usando le faltó ponerle comillas simples '{variable}'

Comment: @LucasDamian gracias. Realmente no programo en python, por tanto no sabía que la `f` servía para eso. De todos modos lo correcto sería que aplique consultas preparadas evitando así la *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Correcto, gracias. Me faltó las comillas simples, estaba reconociendo el valor de la variable como la columna a actualizar, por ello no encontraba esa columna y daba error. Por otro lado, sí vi que se usa consultas separadas, pero para evitar tanto código usaba la f; no sabia que era para evitar inyecciones sql, gracias por el consejo. Aunque esa variable no es proveniente de un formulario, de todas maneras sería correcto hacer consultas separadas para acostumbrarme a eso? O no es necesario en este caso?

Comment: @diegomedina el término correcto es consultas *preparadas*. Si el dato viene de un formulario o de cualquier otra fuente que puede ser manipulada por un usuario hay que usar consultas preparadas porque usuarios mal intencionados (hackers) podrían atacar al sistema haciendo uso de ese dato. Por otra parte las consultas preparadas son más rápidas en escenarios donde tienes que repetir la consulta por algún motivo, ya que el manejador prepara el plan de consulta una sola vez.